# Align text to right

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Today when I saw [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039952/186012), I laughed.

```
A Contradiction $\space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \blacksquare$
```

gives

> A Contradiction $\space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \blacksquare$

I tried to improve it, but I couldn't. All the ways that I knew from $\LaTeX$, didn't work.

HTML too.

```
<div align="right">text</align>
```

`Och! It doesn't work!`

Is here any way to do that?

Comment: "I laughed." I cried. I wish people would *not* do such layout-hacks.

Comment: They could use `\hspace{500px}` to get a similarly ugly result with less typing. MathJax is not meant for page layout. HTML/CSS is, but SE intentionally restricts the allowed HTML tags and strips CSS styles. So, the improvement would be to **not** do that. Some books use a different placement of $\blacksquare$, not right-aligned but at some distance from the text. That would work. $\quad \blacksquare$

Comment: Just don't. You're not writing a math paper, I think people will forgive you if you just write "Qed.", or if the tombstone is not aligned to the right. Think about people on mobile, too -- it will look completely garbled with that huge amount of space.

Comment: Related: [\qed for MathJax here on stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/qed-for-mathjax-here-on-stackexchange)

Comment: I totally understand and I agree, it's not a math paper. Just I wondering, is it possible to do it *correctly*, without compatibility problem. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I edited the example on main.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13338/10513) to a similar question (as linked to in the comments by Martin Sleziak) suggests the hack of `$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$`, which looks like the following:

> ...and the proof is complete. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Frustratingly, it takes a new line. But I do not think this is an issue, as issues go!